# Trouble Shoot Why VBA Stops running mid macro and never finishes execution

Tags: vba, excel

As the title suggests, I was running the below macro. Weirdly enough the msgBox never prompts me with an End Time nor does an error message pop up when the macro stops running. The data in the folders is pretty straight forward stuff, however there are roughly a thousand files its going through

Any pointers on how to trouble shoot this myself? This is something I need to get better at, so suggestions on what to do to figure it out would be nice.

```
      Sub AbesLoop()

 Dim wbk As Workbook
 Dim ws As Integer
 Dim Filename As String
 Dim path As String
 Dim rCell As Range
 Dim rRng As Range
 Dim wsO As Worksheet
 Dim StartTime As Double
 Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
 Dim sheet As Worksheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 StartTime = Timer
 'On Error Resume Next
 path = "PATHtoStuff" & "\"
 Filename = Dir(path & "*.xl??")
 Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

 Do While Len(Filename) > 0
     DoEvents
     Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & Filename, True, True)
     ws = wbk.Worksheets.count
     'For i = 1 To ws
         For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If sheet.Index > 1 Then
                Set rRng = Range("b1:b308")
                For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
                If rCell <> "" And rCell.Value <> "Not Tested" And rCell.Value <> 0 Then
                wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = rCell
                wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = rCell.Offset(0, -1)
                wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Mid(Right(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, 15), 1, 10)
                End If
            Next rCell
            End If
         Next
     'Next i
     wbk.Close False
     Filename = Dir
 Loop

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

 SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
 MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

 End Sub
```

Edit: turns out that for some reasom the loop code is looking at sheet tab 1. I changed the code to try and account for that but for some reason is is still looking at the first page. The error is a "mismatch type" before the dashboard on the first sheet (which I keep trying to circumvent) keeps running into a formula error.

Comment: You won't see any errors as long as your code has `On Error Resume Next` in it. You should *never* use that except under very special circumstances and then only for one or two lines. Comment that out then see what errors there are and what lines are generating them...

Comment: I actually had put that in there to circumvent the original issue but i guess Ill undo it. Thank you

Comment: I have no idea what the original issue was/is so I can't really comment on that. But when this is needed for a small bit, use `On Error GoTo 0` to turn errors back on.

Comment: OK This is weird. One of the workbooks opens up in "Design Mode" and then the macro halts. Still no error message and no debug line in VBA. Im going to go find the file and see if it was saved weird or whatever

Comment: What happens if you change the path to a folder with a small number of files?

Comment: I guess I can try that too

Comment: If the workbook is opening in Design Mode that will stop macro execution. I believe there is a circumstance (in some versions of Office) that forces opening in Design Mode, but memory is failing me as to the reason... Something to do with macro security/ActiveX? The file contains ActiveX controls but their execution isn't allowed under current security settings?

Comment: I altered my code based on further findings

Comment: I think you need to check exactly what Range (`Range("b1:b308")`) is pointing at. Excel isn't really my expertise, but I suspect you need to specify which Worksheet this Range is supposed to be on.

Comment: I may try that. I thought after setting it after the "check for sheet logic" that it would've known to only set that range for that worksheet. thank you

Comment: If you want to loop through a bunch of files I heartily suggest looking into the filesystemobject https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711216%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I htink I solved my very obvious issue. Not at work anymore, but I started messing around with a smaller version on my home computer. The issue was mainly the script was not skipping the first sheet in a row. this syntax fixed it "Set rRng = sheet.Range("b1:b10")" Ill post back tomorrow when I try it on the much larger version. Basically @CindyMeister was correct- not telling it where to look caused the error.

Comment: @CindyMeister If you want to post an actual answer with the information I posted in my previous comment, Ill check it for you so you can get rep. Also, this thing did work with the 1000 fiel example. Ran in 25 minutes eesh! Now to work on the performance tips someone gave me in code review!

Comment: Although this is solved (it seems) some general advice for figuring out what code is doing is to add breakpoints (so that the debugger stops execution and you can see what it is doing) or add `Debug.Print "some message"` lines so that you can get feedback (in the Immediate window) of where the code is executing.  With a couple `Debug.Print` calls in a loop, you will never lose track of the code.  These will update even if `ScreenUpdating` is turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working in VBA that's part of an application it's important to use the *objects* provided by the application, rather than generalized Selection or ActiveWorkbook, etc. This code is doing that, which is good :-)

At the same time, however, VBA needs to be able to uniquely identify object with which it should work. With "Selection" or "Active[Thing]" that's not necessary, so this step isn't something easily learned using the macro recorder.

In the case of the code in this question

```
Set rRng = Range("b1:b308")
```

It's not clear to Excel from which worksheet the Range should be taken, so it's defaulting to the first worksheet in the workbook. Instead, use:

```
Set rRng = sheet.Range("b1:b10")"
```